# Count No of times Program has been executed

Tags: java

How can I get the number of times a program has previously run in java  without keeping a file and tallying. Is there a Application class or something in java to check the count

Comment: Is this web based application or standalone application?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html).  This eliminates the need for *you* to do the file i/o.  You will still need to read the preference value, increment it, and then store the new value.

On Windows, the preferences API uses the registry.  On Unix, the preferences API uses the file system as the backing store (but this is hidden from you as a developer).

You can get/store preferences for either the system, or for an individual user.  (It's not clear if you want to know how many times a *user* ran the program, or how many times *anyone* on said computer ran the program).  Look for [`Preferences.systemNodeForPackage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#systemNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29) and [`Preferences.userNodeForPackage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29) in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public class Test {

    private static int INSTANCE_COUNTER = 0;

    public Test() {

        INSTANCE_COUNTER++;
    }

    public static final int getInstanceCounter() {

        return INSTANCE_COUNTER;
    }

    //-Methods-//
}
```

Now, you can call Test.getInstanceCounter() to get the number.

Comment: And when you exit the program and start it again ? The `INSTANCE_COUNTER` will be 0 again. Maybe if you would suggested to serialize the class `Test`, maybe we would get somewhere...

Comment: @SoboLAN: serialisation still requires you to read and write a file though.

Comment: @both: If he needs the count for all execution of a particular class, then I guess he has to use files directly or indirectly!